# how to use cursor in sqlite3 in c++ implementation?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am facing a performance issue when we fetch one row at a time from a `sqlite3` fetch wrapper that we have written . Following is the pseudo code:

```
if(sqlStatement.startEvaluation())
{
    while(sqlStatement.fetchNext())
    {
        <Some Type> node(reinterpret_cast<type>(sqlStatement.getPointer(0)));
            m_result.push_back(node);
    }
}

bool rttSQLiteStatement::fetchNext()
{
    try
    {
        int result = sqlite3_step(m_statement);
        if(result==SQLITE_ROW)
            return true;

        if(result!=SQLITE_DONE)
            setError("Unable to fetch row.");

        return false;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Error while fetching next query result.");
        return false;
    }   
}

void* rttSQLiteStatement::getPointer(int i)
{
    try
    {
        assert(m_statement);
        assert(i<m_numResultColumns);
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(sqlite3_column_int64(m_statement, i));
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Error while reading pointer query result.");
        return false;
    }   
}
```

I want to use something like a cursor which would give me all the results in a record set

Comment: In the SQLite C API, a statement and its cursor are handled by the same object (`sqlite3_stmt`). There is nothing wrong with this code. What exactly is the performance problem?

Comment: Actually I get the feeling the performance problem is in  while(sqlStatement.fetchNext()) ..which is fetching one record at a time . Is it possible to fetch all the records in a cursor ?or u mean to say that sqlite3_step already gives me a cursor ?

Comment: The `sqlite3_stmt` object *is* the cursor. You can fetch all records by calling `sqlite3_step()` multiple times.

Comment: @CL the `sqlite3_step` is using a mutex ..do u think it might degrade the performance ?

Comment: Most likely reason for degraded performance is a query statement with join(s) not using keys which will cause whole table scans and/or temporary tables to be required.  You need to use the query planner ( https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html ) and check how your statement is being executed.  Also please qualify _"performance issue"_ and show the query.

Comment: This question is unanswerable. If you want to know how to speed up your query, ask a question about that specific query.